# Alert display on top of Modal Popup asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, alert, modalpopupextender

I'm wondering how, if possible, to display an alertbox over a modal pop. I'm using the modal popup extender to display a form which the user fills out. On the form there are fields that the user must fill out, if they don't fill out a field and click submit then I want to display an alert box. As it is right now, I can't get the alertbox to display at all while the modalpopup is still active. Here is the code for the alertbox I'm trying to use:

```
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "error", "alert('Please coomplete all of the required fields');", true);
```

Comment: I ended up finding the solution. Turns out "Page.Clientscript...." won't work because the modalpop up doesn't belong to Page. Instead use:

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('your message');", true);

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
 string Msg = "Your Message";
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('" + Msg + " .');</script>");
```

It works fine for me